# occurrence of char with respect to its neighbor in haskell

Tags: haskell

i have a string something like that

```
test = "fDfDfadsptupauOasufDfDfadsptupausapasdfogfdifdsudsaufuffxDfDfDfDfDfDfadsptupauOasufDfDfadsptupausap"
```

and i would like to get the number of the occurrence for example of the char '0' with respect to the char coming after the '0' , so for example for the string test when i call my function it should give

```
 ('0',[(8,'w'),(2,'q')])
```

which means that char '0' occurs 8 times in the form "0w" and 2 times in the form "2q"

until now i manged to the total occurrence of '0' which is 10 but i cannot get it with respect to its neighbor , my code

```
freq c l = filter (==c) l
function::[(Char ,Int)]
function = [('0' , sum (map length (map (freq '0') test)))]
```

note my output should be of the type

```
function :: [(Char,[(Int,Char)])
```

Comment: This might be unrelated to what you want to do, but have you looked at the markov-chain package?

Answer (score 4):

Think about how you can transform your data, a `String` into something that can be processed to give you the result you want.  What you're really interested in is pairs of adjacent characters, so your first step would be to write a function which pairs each element with its successor:

```
matchSuccessors :: String -> [(Char, Char)]
matchSuccessors text = undefined
```

Then you want to group these together by what the first element is, such as `'0'`.  For this you'll want to look at `sort/sortBy` and `group/groupBy` in `Data.List`:

```
organizeSuccessors :: [(Char, Char)] -> [[(Char, Char)]]
organizeSuccessors succs = undefined
```

At this point you should have something like

```
> organizeSuccessors (matchSuccessors "abababacacabac")
[[('a','b'),('a','b'),('a','b'),('a','b')],
 [('a','c'),('a','c'),('a','c')],
 [('b','a'),('b','a'),('b','a'),('b','a')],
 [('c','a'),('c','a')]
]
```

(whitespace added for readability)

Now you can very easily measure the length of each, pairing that with what element it was:

```
countSuccessorGroups :: [[(Char, Char)]] -> [((Char, Char), Int)]
countSuccessorGroups grps = map (\grp -> (head grp, length grp)) grps
```

So now you would see

```
> countSuccessorGroups $ organizeSuccessors $ matchSuccessors "abababacacabac"
[(('a', 'b'), 4),
 (('a', 'c'), 3),
 (('b', 'a'), 4),
 (('c', 'a'), 2)
]
```

Now armed with your knowledge of `sortBy` and `groupBy` you should be able to convert this into what you need:

```
organizeByFirstLetter :: [((Char, Char), Int)] -> [(Char, [(Int, Char)])]
organizeByFirstLetter succgrps = undefined
```

So your entire program would be

```
function
    = organizeByFirstLetter
    $ countSuccessorGroups
    $ organizeSuccessors
    $ matchSuccessors
    $ test
```

You can also break up `organizeByFirstLetter` into multiple steps as necessary.

Comment: great idea , but could you please define the first 2 functions as i am stuck .

Comment: @Halawa What are you stuck on?  I don't want to just give you the solution, I want you to figure it out yourself.  Focus just on the first function, do you know of a way to pair elements of two lists together?  If you can pair the elements of two lists together, then dropping the first character of your text leaves you with two lists, including the original text.

Comment: i see your point of view but the problem is that i am a kind of new to haskell :D so it is a little bit hard for me to do that

Comment: @Halawa The first function can be built using `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]` combined with `tail`.  The `tail` function returns all but the first element of a list, and `zip` makes tuples by combining two lists element-wise.  So you'd have `matchSuccessors text = zip text (tail text)`.  Does that help you get started?

Comment: i have been trying to solve it for the last 2 hours and you made in one line :D thank you i think it is very hard for me because i am not an expert in the predefined functions in haskell

Comment: If you haven't seen it, check out [hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle) where you can search for function names, types, or even partial types.  You can search for something like [`String -> String -> [(Char, Char)]`](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=String+-%3E+String+-%3E+[%28Char%2C+Char%29]&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09), and it brings up the more general `zip` function first.

Comment: could you please give me your mail or facebook or anything to contact you ?

Comment: @Halawa Sorry, no, I don't pass out my information very much.  You're welcome to keep asking questions here on SO, now you have several functions that you can ask individual questions about, and there are other places you can get help from the community in general.  The IRC channels are pretty friendly, and reddit.com/r/haskell usually treats newcomers well if it's a well written question.